# Cannot commit when auto commit is enabled (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is a part of the code which causes problem.

```
//Create buffered row set
crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
crs.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:adam");
crs.setUsername("adam");
crs.setPassword("1234");
crs.setCommand("SELECT name, description, price FROM products");
crs.execute();
crs.next(); //Move cursor to the first record
//Update the first record
crs.updateString("name", "TEST NAME");
crs.updateString("description", "TEST DESC");
crs.updateFloat("price", 1);
crs.updateRow();
crs.acceptChanges();
```

On acceptChanges() line I get an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.commit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:705)
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.commit(CachedRowSetWriter.java:1396)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:893)
    at test.MainPanel$2.actionPerformed(MainPanel.java:70)
    ...
```

How to get it work? I know about setAutoCommit(false) method but when I call

```
crs.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
```

i get the NullPointerException because getConnection() returns null. Please help